# apc_store() only works in some directories?

Tags: php, apc

<s>I am using PHP's `apc_store()` and `apc_fetch()` to store variables.</s>

For PHP files in Apache's document root (including subdirectories), the APC functions work fine.

However, when I use APC functions in other directories (anything but the document root), `apc_store()` doesn't work. I can't store any variables.

How can I make APC work in other directories?

EDIT:
I realized that whether or not APC worked wasn't dependent on the directory. Rather, I had to use the terminal to run anything that wasn't in the document root. If I used a terminal to run the file in the document root, APC doesn't work either. So the question becomes: how do I use APC with a terminal?

Comment: what is "apache's root directory"?

Comment: I meant the document root.

Comment: And what do you mean by "store variables *in Apache's root directory*"? The variables stored by APC are not scoped to the filesystem.

Comment: The files with `apc_store()` are in the document root.